# Learning probability distribution with scikit learn random forests?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataset of state->action pairs, (s,a), where each s defines a probability distribution over the possible choices of a, and each a is sampled from that probability distribution. I'd like to train a classifier for this dataset, where rather than learning to predict the maximum likelihood, it predicts the distribution a was sampled from.

For example, if you're playing an iterative rock-paper-scissors, your state may be just the previous move you made and a ∈ { Rock, Paper, Scissors }, where the previous state reduces the probability of choosing that action again. My dataset would then look like:

```
PreviousAction,Chosen
Rock,Paper
Paper,Rock
Rock,Scissors
Scissors,Paper
Paper,Paper
...
```

Is it possible to learn probability distributions over the labels with random forests in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Train a [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier) using `fit` (which expects labels, not probability distributions, as its `y` argument), then predict using `predict_proba`.